# how come git bash can call java tools (xjc.exe) with unix paths but not cygwin?

Tags: bash, java, git, cygwin, cmd.exe

From CMD.exe, I can run xjc as follows:

```
xjc "c:/schema.xsd" -p abc -d "temp"
```

From git Bash, I can run xjc as follows:

```
xjc "/c/schema.xsd" -p abc -d "temp"
```

As far as Cygwin goes, I can get it work only if I call xjc.exe using the CMD.exe syntax.

This is problematic because the script that ran into this problem relies on ${PWD} to get the path to the current directory, which resolves to "/c", not "c:/".

Even with a hack to replace "/c" with "c:/", I'd still like to know why xjc accepts a unix path when called by git Bash but not by Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. you are using a windows executable that expects windows paths and
2. bash expands paths to its own native cygwin paths.

In cygwin, a correct path for `c:\schema.xsd` would translate into `/cygdrive/c/schema.xsd` (**not** `/c/schema.xsd`, unless you created a symlink.)
Why git-bash (is that the one shipped by msysgit?) allows you to use `/c/schema.xsd` as valid path, is beyond me.

When you call xcj with one file as parameter (that bash/cygwin recognizes), it will receive the filehandle and not its path. If it's just a string however, that string will be passed as parameter to the application without further parsing and string expansion.

You can either approach this issue by trying to use cygpath (see [using-cygwin-effectively](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) and [cygpath-info](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath)) to pass on the correct windows path or, if it's only one file, try to pass on the correct (unix/cygwin) file path.